# UIView with container view not scrolling properly when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, uiview, uicontainerview

I have an issue dealing with a `UIContainerView` inside a `UIView`. When I try to show the keyboard to edit one of the fields I would expect the whole `UIView` (with the `UIContainerView` inside it) to scroll up and out of the way of the keyboard.

Here is what I see at the moment. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic scrolling for input only happens in things like `UITableView`. For this one, refer to the Apple guide of [managing keyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html).

Essentially, you want to manually scroll up the view when the keyboards appear and put it back when the keyboard is hidden.

Edit: I just realised that you have a 
`UITableViewController`. My guess would be because it's on fullscreen, the table view doesn't have enough room to scroll. In this case, you would need to put the all the views inside a scroll view and follow the guide above.